# Repetition in data constructor

Tags: haskell

I can define a binary tree data structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Now I want to create a tree such that each `Node` has 10 sub-trees. I could so so by writing out 10 `(Tree a)`s, but is there a more consise way? I'm thinking type families might help here but I'm not sure.

Comment: Using such a tree might be cumbersome. A simple solution would be to just store a list of children, `data Tree a = Leaf | Node a [Tree a]` and enforce a limit of 10 children at run time. A more complicated answer would use type-level integers to constrain the second argument of `Node` to lists of length 10.

Comment: The following incantation is to be pronounced with tongue tucked firmly in cheek: `type Triple t = (t, t, t); data Tree t = Tea | Timber t (Tree t) (Triple (Triple (Tree t)))`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want a tree whose branching factor is determined on the type level, and can be any natural number. This is fairly straightforward with GADTs:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat 

data Vec (n :: Nat) a where 
  Nil :: Vec 'Z a 
  (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a 
infixr 5 :> 

data Tree k a = Leaf | Node a (Vec k (Tree k a))
```

`Vec` is the standard way to encode a homogenous length-indexed vector with GADTs (found e.g. [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-1.4.3.1)). A node in a tree is then an element of type `a` and a vector of length `k`, where each element of the vector is a subtree.

Binary trees are simply

```
type BinaryTree = Tree ('S ('S 'Z))
```

and constructing is simply

```
tree = Node 1 (Node 2 (Leaf :> Leaf :> Nil) :> Leaf :> Nil)
```

the inferred type will be `Num a => Tree ('S ('S 'Z)) a`.

But if you really need 10 nodes, writing out ten `'S` is still too tedious, so you may want to use type literals:

```
import qualified GHC.TypeLits as TL

...

type family N (n :: TL.Nat) :: Nat where  
  N 0 = 'Z 
  N n = 'S (N (n TL.- 1))

type Tree10 = Tree (N 10)
```

This not only gives you trees with any branching factor you like, but it allows you to write functions which are polymorphic in the branching factor, and even more, GHC give you all the following for free:

```
-- With StandaloneDeriving, DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable
deriving instance Functor (Vec k) 
deriving instance Foldable (Vec k) 
deriving instance Traversable (Vec k) 

deriving instance Functor (Tree k)
deriving instance Foldable (Tree k) 
deriving instance Traversable (Tree k)
```